# comma after last key-value pair in dictionary

Tags: python

```
color_points = {
        "green" : 1,
        "blue" : 2,
        "ornage" : 3,
        "red" : 4,
        "purple" : 5,
        "black" : 6,
        }
```

Should I add a comma after the last key-value pair in a dictionary (is it good practice) or can I go without it ?

Comment: there's no difference on commented code :)

Comment: Yes, indeed, question modified. Thank you.

Comment: "Can you"? Absolutely. Python doesn't *need* it.

Comment: I mostly do it because it makes it easier to re-arrange the item pairs or append new ones without getting pesky syntax errors. :)

Answer (score 1):

It is good practice in the sense that you will get better diffs when adding items. See Raymond Hettinger's (core dev) lectures for more stuff like this.

Comment: Indeed, spelling edited.